# android single fragment - 2 horizontal videos list

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to design a Screen layout with android fragment. Screen have 2 label and 2 gallery and they are arrange in this fashion

```
Label1 -> gallery1 -> label2 -> gallery2.
```

Gallery has a horizontal list of videos. gallery 1 & gallery2 has different list of videos.

I want to design the gallery with fragment so that I can use single fragment for both gallery using same adapter. Since their video list is different, I don't know, if I use a single fragment for both gallery in android layout how can I ensure different horizontal list of videos using a single fragment ?

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use same fragment class. You will need two instances of adapters though for gallery1 and gallery2. Instantiate those adapters with different videos as needed.

EDIT: This is just an overview of how your code should be. Not actual code but very rough pseudo code.

main layout xml file -

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
<TextView
<Gallery id="g1"
<TextView
<Gallery id="g2"
```

gallery adapter xml -

java file-

```
GalleryAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
adapter1.settype(1);
adapter2.settype(2);
((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.g1)).setAdapter(adapter1);
((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.g2)).setAdapter(adapter2);
```

in the adapter file inherited from BaseAdapter, set a type variable and based on the value initiate it with diff values but same xml. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: can you please explain me more. how can i use the same fragment?